# overriding class methods: including the superclass method in the subclass method JAVA

Tags: subclass, overriding, superclass

So I have these to classes, one is my superclass the other is my subclass. I am having trouble calling my sub class method in my superclass method so I can get these results also. the methods are overloading and I am having a problem understanding it. I think If I can get this, it will help me understand how the two interlink and work.
I am having trouble in my copy constructor, toString method and equals method in my subclass

Superclass:

```
public class Car
{
        private String make;
    private String model;
        private int miles;
  //    The default constructor—use this
        public Car()
        {
                this.make=null;
            this.model=null;
        this.miles=0;
        }
//  The 3-parameter constructor –use this
        public Car(String make,String model,int miles)
        {
            this.make=make;
            this.model=model;
            this.miles=miles;
        }
//  The copy constructor—use this
        public Car(Car obj)
        {
            this.make=obj.make;
            this.model=obj.model;
            this.miles=obj.miles;
        }
 // The toString method—use this
        public String toString()
        {
            String str;
                    str = "The car Brand: "+ this.make +" Mobel: "+this.model+" miles on the car: "+this.miles;
            return str;
        }
//  The equals method—use this
    public boolean equals(Car obj)
    {
        if      (this.make.equals(obj.make)&&this.model.equals(obj.model)&&this.miles==obj.miles)
            return true;
        else
            return false;
    }   

 }

 //My subclass method

public class Convertible extends Car
  {
        private String typeTop;
 // The default constructor—use this
        public Convertible()
        {
            super();
            this.typeTop= null;
        }
//  The 4-parameter constructor—use this
        public Convertible(String make, String model,int miles,String typeTop)
        {
            super(make,model,miles);
        this.typeTop=typeTop;
        }
 // The copy constructor—use this
        public Convertible(Convertible obj)
        {
            super(Convertible obj);
        this.typeTop=obj.typeTop;
        }
 // The toString method—use this
        public String toString()
        {
            String str;
            str =super.toString()+this.typeTop;
            return str;
        }
 // The equals method—use this
    public boolean equals(Convertible obj)
    {
        if(super.equals(super.obj)&&this.typeTop.equals(obj.typeTop))
            return true;
        else
            return false;
    }


 }
```

Comment: I think I found a way to make my copy method, is this correct?
 public Convertible(Convertible obj)
  {
   super(obj) ;
   this.typeTop=obj.typeTop;
  }

Answer (score 0):

change line number 29 in Convertible class to `super(obj);`

and 43 to `if (super.equals(obj) && this.typeTop.equals(obj.typeTop)) {`

Comment: hey thanks, I though so, I was wondering what I was doing wrong.

Comment: u call super constructor with the type of argument like this super(Convertible obj); but it must be called on the object directly super(obj); ok ?

Comment: yes sir, thank you I saw what I was doing wrong. Those little mistakes and overlooking them cause problems for me.